# Sublime text 3 SideBarEnhancements plugin - cannot close 2nd view

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I installed SideBarEnhancements plugin on Sublime Text 3. In the left sidebar where the files are listed, I right-clicked -> Edit To Right. It opened another view. Now I can't seem to close it by any means. [image]

Comment: My bad, it was a setting with in sublime that caused it. View -> Layout -> Single. That did the trick

Answer (score 5):

it was a setting with in sublime that caused it. View -> Layout -> Single. That did the trick

Comment: thanks for the answer, I was looking for a way to close it as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That was pretty annoying for me :)